# When are the React PropTypes checks executed?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

When the PropTypes are defined in a component, there is a certain expectation that these will check the type of the props when they are received. But it's clear that components can receive a prop value before it has been populated with the expected value and, therefore, the PropType warnings appear as a result. So at what point in the component lifecycle are the type checks being run?

Answer (score 3):

This is the factory that bundles in the validation:

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactElementValidator.js

When in dev mode, it is used here:

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/8af6728c6f105d37f9c0006288a6d1ac3903dc71/packages/react/src/React.js#L61-L63

So, it looks like it's at the create/clone stage when props are being passed, for instance, bottom of the create element factory calls it: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactElementValidator.js#L262-L333

If you late-change a valid prop to an invalid one, it either must clone or recreate the element (if it fires a warning) but I don't have the time to confirm this, you can easily create a basic class with loggers for lifecycle methods to verify.

you can search for `checkPropTypes` in the react repo root and find all uses internally.

Comment: I couldn't find if it is revalidated at each render or only if the corresponding prop change... would you know it?